# jquery VirtualKeyboard incorrect position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, virtual-keyboard

I'm using the [Mottie/Keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) plugin and I'm having problems while positioning the keyboard.
The images sums it up what I want and what's happening.

[image]

As you can see, the keyboard always goes to the TOP-LEFT of the screen no matter what I do.

You can also see that I'm using a modal, however the same behavior happens to all inputs no matter if on a modal or not.

In this case, I would like the keyboard to happear below the modal.

```
$('#quantity-input').keyboard(
{
    layout  : 'num',
    usePreview: false,
    restrictInput: false,
    preventPaste: true,
    autoAccept: true,
      position     : {
        // optional - null (attach to input/textarea) or a jQuery object
        // (attach elsewhere)
        of : $('.modal'),
        my : 'center bottom',
        at : 'center bottom',
        // used when "usePreview" is false
        // (centers keyboard at bottom of the input/textarea)
        at2: 'center bottom'
      },
});
```

I've also tried to change the position property `of` to other elements such as:

```
$(window)
$(this)
$('#quantity-input')
$('body')
```

And nothing works.
My CSS and JS files are the following:

```
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap.min.js
keyboard.min.css
jquery-wijmo.css
bootstrap.min.js
keyboard.min.js
```

**EDIT**: 
You can see the problem on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cfyjhgw/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved.**

After find out the [same issue](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/388) in Github by another guy, I also find out that I need to use jquery-ui css and js files, which I wasn't using.

Comment: You can also use css to position the keyboard - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/egb3a1sk/493/). No jQuery UI required.